# How to Convert ManagedCursorStreamProvider to application/json-patch+json?

Tags: dataweave, mule4

Hi My input payload in application/json-patch+json  format and am sending it as application/json-patch+json from postman.I need to pass this payload into a java class. In Java class when i am receiving it , it showing as type class org.mule.runtime.core.internal.streaming.bytes.ManagedCursorStreamProvider(Printing it as inputPayload.getClass() in Java class).In Java class i am accepting it as an Object . I want it to receive it as com.github.fge.jsonpatch.JsonPatch or need to cast it in java class .

My payload is

```
[
 {
 "path": "baseLoanAmount",
 "value": "10000.00"
 }
]
```

passing this payload as java.lang.Object into Java class like

```
test(java.lang.Object)

input arguments as 
{
inputPayload: payload
}
```

How we can achieve it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing `payload.^raw` as the argument.

Comment: Reference: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-cookbook-extract-data#metadata_selector